# Check Keyboard is open or not in react native?

Tags: react-native

**I simply want to improve my code.**
I want to check whether keyboard is open or not in Android in IOS through React Native so on that basis I can make changes accordingly.

Here is my code snippet how I am doing it right now.

```
const [isKeyboardVisible, setKeyboardVisible] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener(
            'keyboardDidShow',
            () => {
                setKeyboardVisible(true);
            },
        );
        const keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener(
            'keyboardDidHide',
            () => {
                setKeyboardVisible(false);
            },
        );

        return () => {
            keyboardDidHideListener.remove();
            keyboardDidShowListener.remove();
        };
    }, []);
```

This code gives true in case keyboard is open and false when keyboard is not open.

Thanks in advance

I checked stack overflow, found many solutions but,
**All I need is a simple and shorter solution for this.**

Comment: You are doing in a right way as It's the recommended way of handling keyboard visibility and also showing here you can check https://reactnative.dev/docs/keyboard

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom hook if you want a shorter version of it.

Here's a sample `keyboard.js`

```
export const useKeyboardVisible = () => {
    const [isKeyboardVisible, setKeyboardVisible] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener(
            'keyboardDidShow',
            () => setKeyboardVisible(true),
        );
        const keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener(
            'keyboardDidHide',
            () => setKeyboardVisible(false),
        );

        return () => {
            keyboardDidHideListener.remove();
            keyboardDidShowListener.remove();
        };
    }, []);

    return isKeyboardVisible;
}
```

Then you can simply import it to your components

```
const SampleComponent = () => {
   const isKeyboardVisible = useKeyboardVisible();

   // ...
}
``
```